# Looking for an Idea how to create multiple MSI

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I have to create an installation tool for a customer which has to do this:

1) create a "main" MSI which creates a database on MSSQL and run SQL Scripts
the User can decide which server to take, the Database-Name,  User-Name and so on. 
2) when done, 2 MSIs have to be created for: 
1 Service APP which should be installed on a windows server 
and 1 GUI which can be installed on any PC.

my Problem: How to give the Database Settings from step 1 to the MSI packages needed for Step 2?

what I did:
With Inno setup I can run the Database Installation and the SQL Scripts.
Then I create an XML file with the connection strings and recompile the MSIs with the Inno Compiler needed for Step 2.
This is not "comfortable" for the user and it is not stable.

Do you have a better idea how to do this?

---

// explanation how I create the other MSI Packages:
After the Dtabase has been created by the User I call a small app which does this:

string INNOCLI = "ISCC.exe";
                    string arg = string.Format("/O{0} {0}\serviceonlysetup.iss", temIntalationDirectory);

```
                using (Process cli = new Process())
                {
                    cli.StartInfo.FileName = INNOCLI;
                    cli.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
                    cli.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    cli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cli.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    cli.Start();
                    cli.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    cli.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    cli.WaitForExit();
                }

                if (!Directory.Exists(guiInstallDirectory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(guiInstallDirectory);
                }

                string argServ = string.Format("/O{0} {0}\\guionlysetup.iss", temIntalationDirectory);

                using (Process cli = new Process())
                {
                    cli.StartInfo.FileName = INNOCLI;
                    cli.StartInfo.Arguments = argServ;
                    cli.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    cli.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cli.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    cli.Start();
                    cli.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    cli.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    cli.WaitForExit();
                }

                if (File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\dwhservice_setup.exe", serviceInstallDirectory)))
                {
                    File.Delete(string.Format("{0}\\dwhservice_setup.exe", serviceInstallDirectory));
                }

                if (File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\dwhgui_setup.exe", guiInstallDirectory)))
                {
                    File.Delete(string.Format("{0}\\dwhgui_setup.exe", guiInstallDirectory));
                }

                File.Move(string.Format("{0}\\dwhservice_setup.exe", temIntalationDirectory), string.Format("{0}\\dwhservice_setup.exe", serviceInstallDirectory));
                File.Move(string.Format("{0}\\dwhgui_setup.exe", temIntalationDirectory), string.Format("{0}\\dwhgui_setup.exe", guiInstallDirectory));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
```

Later I have to have a MSI for a service and a MSI for an User Interface. Both have to have the Database Credentials from step 1

Comment: Inno Setup cannot create msi. Please explain.

Comment: Why do you eves have two separate installers for the two steps?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I add the Inno compiler to my filelist: Iscc compiler files\Compil32.exe and use this later after creating the database. Reason I do this because a Service has to be installed and needs the database credentials which are created in step 1. A Maintainance app which handles the settings for the service app can be used by everyone so another MSI package has to be created.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment didn't answer any of my questions. Also what "filelist" do you mean? Show us some code/script.

Comment: After your edit: You still didn't explain how do you create .msi with Inno Setup. Inno Setup does not support creating MSIs. + You didn't explain why you compile an installer from another installer.